# How do I properly implement a binary search algorithm to guess a random BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, search, biginteger

I am writing a program that is supposed to guess a randomly generated BigInteger from another program. The number class gives feedback on whether my guess was higher or lower than the number ("correct" if the answer is correct).  While my program works fine and correctly guesses the BigInteger, my binary search algorithm I implemented is performing less efficiently than I expected. I have been racking my brain and can't figure out why the number of guesses (after the bit is found) exceeds log(n) time.

I've been counting the number of guesses guesses and the first part of my code (that finds the proper bit of the big int) performs exceptionally well, usually only requiring a handful of guesses.

```
public static BigInteger guesser(Number n) {
    int guesses=0;

    String feedback = n.guess(BigInteger.ONE); 
    guesses++;

    if (feedback.equals("correct")){
        return BigInteger.ONE;

    } else{
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger max = two;
        BigInteger min = max;
        BigInteger mid;

        if(n.guess(max).equals("correct")) {
            return max;
        }

        while (!feedback.equals("lower")) {
            min = max;
            max = max.pow(2);
            feedback=n.guess(max); 
                    guesses++;
        }

        mid = min.add(max).divide(two);
        feedback = n.guess(mid); 
            guesses++;

        while (!feedback.equals("correct")){
            if (feedback.equals("higher")){
                min=mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            } else if (feedback.equals("lower")){
                max=mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            } 
            mid= min.add(max).divide(two);
            feedback = n.guess(mid); 
                guesses++;
        }
        return mid;
    }
```

The binary search algorithm portion of the code racks up a huge number of guesses and I can't figure out why. For a 38119 bit BigInteger, it takes the program approximately twice that number of guesses. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is there a simple error here that I'm overlooking? Shouldn't the number of guesses be approximately equal to 2log(n)?

Comment: Is this portion of your code ` while (!feedback.equals("lower")) {
            min = max;
            max = max.pow(2);
            feedback=n.guess(max); 
                    guesses++;
        }
` racking up the extra guesses?  I'm used to seeing a min / mid / max that starts with with min = mininmum possible value, max = maximum possible value, and then just keep splitting the list in half from there

Comment: Also do you have to contend with possible negative values at all?

Comment: So the reason for that portion of the code is that the BigInteger has no upper bound, so I am increasing my guesses exponentially in order to find the number of bits that the value has. This part runs in O(log n) time. It is the actual binary search part that is racking up guesses, I just can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: Nope, no negative values. It is assumed that this BigInteger is greater than 0.

Comment: FWIW, `max := max.pow(2);`is probably quite a bit slower than `max := max.multiply(max);`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are going too high with exponential search. When the number is big enough the first number you find is a lot higher than it needs to be.

Let's say the number you want to guess is `43263289412904812894021841098214912804215324`, looking for the upper range by applying `pow(2)` the first number you are gonna hit is `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936` - that is so much higher, it takes so much attempts just to return back to close proximity.

Now lets say you applied `multiply(new BigInteger("25"))` instead - the first number you hit is `43368086899420177360298112034797668457031250`. Yes, it takes more attempts to get to that number, but it's worth it in the end, because the last `pow(2)` on such a huge number creates so big overkill that it's hard to come back. I used a small number here, but it gets worse and worse with bigger numbers.

In my opinion - you should find balance between applying pow and multiplication while finding the upper bound. Maybe if a number is big enough then stop exponentiation and start multiplication by some value and make this value higher as the bound gets higher.

I used a small value in my example above, but with `38119` bit BigInteger:

- `pow(2)` - upper bound 17 guesses - all guesses 65552
- `multiply(new BigInteger("25"))` - upper bound 8209 guesses - all guesses 46327
- `multiply(new BigInteger("100"))` - upper bound 5738 guesses - all guesses 43854
- `multiply(new BigInteger("1000"))` - upper bound 3826 guesses - all guesses 41946
- `multiply(new BigInteger("10000"))` - upper bound 2870 guesses - all guesses 40994
- `multiply(new BigInteger("50000"))` - upper bound 2443 guesses - all guesses 40562
- `multiply(new BigInteger("100000"))` - upper bound 2296 guesses - all guesses 40416

It takes a lot more guesses to get to the upper bound, but then we are a lot closer to the final value, so it's still worth it. Notice that it stops being worth at some point.

Comment: Instead of multiplying by a fixed number, it is probably much more performant to shiftLeft() by a fixed number of bits, e.g. 16 or 32. Of course this advantage may be completely lost by a slow guess() function. +1 anyway.

Comment: FWIW, with 38119 bits and shifts of 32 bits the upper bound would be found in (38119 + 31) / 32 = 1192 guesses for the upper bound (plus ~ 38119 + 31 guesses for the exact number).